# Restrict changing to root user

Tags: linux, users, su

For security reasons my system boot with "guest" user or nobody.
If that user run the "su root" command he will change to root user therefore gain access to all files owned by root.

Since I can run only 1 serial terminal I would like to restrict that option:

If any user would like to change to root he will need to enter root's password.

how can I do that?

Comment: When you type `su root` it will ask you to enter root password.

Comment: For me it's not: the system performs autologin using agetty -a .. and then I can change to root using su.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my root user didn't had password at all.
the /etc/passwd point that the password will be at /etc/shadow (by showing x instead of password) and in /etc/shadow I saw there is no password for root. I added one and now whenever I change from one user to root it prompt for its password